# Ignite serialization issue in QueryCursor

Tags: ignite

I’m quite new to ignite and trying to 'seed' cache from EntryProcessor but can't traverse ScanQuery's results in application

I have ignite v2.6.0 cluster with two atomic partitioned caches and peer class loading enabled:

```
Cache A : IgniteCache<Long, A>
Cache B : IgniteCache<UUID, ScheduledTask>


interface ScheduledTask extends Serializable {
     Instant getExecuteAt()
}

one of classes that are stored in cache B:

class ExpirationTask implements ScheduledTask
```

Spring boot application (written in Kotlin) asynchronously invokes entry processor against cache A. Processor populates data in both caches (A and B). Then application queries cache B:

```
 val dueQuery = ScanQuery<UUID, ScheduledTask> { _, task -> task.executeAt <= now }

       bCache.query(dueQuery, { it.key }).use { taskKeys ->
            for (taskKey in taskKeys) {
   ………………………
          }
}
```

But query cursor throws ClassCastException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: ExpirationTask cannot be cast to ScheduledTask
    at ….Scheduler$poll$dueQuery$1.apply(Scheduler:61)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$ScanQueryIterator.advance(GridCacheQueryManager.java:3089)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$ScanQueryIterator.onHasNext(GridCacheQueryManager.java:2982)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNextX(GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.java:53)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.GridIteratorAdapter.hasNext(GridIteratorAdapter.java:45)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.runQuery(GridCacheQueryManager.java:1164)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.processQueryRequest(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:230)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$2.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$2.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1054)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:579)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:378)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:304)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:99)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:293)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1556)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1184)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:125)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1091)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Both A and B classes are marshaled by OptimizedMarshaller because of custom serialization like:

```
data class B(val dueTime: Instant, val id: Long) : ScheduledTask {

 override fun getExecuteAt(): Instant {
        return dueTime
    }
    private fun writeObject(stream: ObjectOutputStream) {
        // Only used to indicate custom serialization for Ignite. Real work done by writeReplace()
    }

    private fun readObject(stream: ObjectInputStream) {
        // Only used to indicate custom serialization for Ignite. Real work done by writeReplace()
    }

    private fun writeReplace(): Any = Serializer(this)

    class Serializer @JvmOverloads constructor(var source: B? = null) : Externalizable {
        override fun readExternal(stream: ObjectInput) {
            val dueTime = stream.readObject() as Instant
            val id = stream.readLong()
           source = B(dueTime, id)
        }

        override fun writeExternal(stream: ObjectOutput) {
            stream.writeObject(source!!.dueTime)
            stream.writeLong(source!!.id)
       }

        private fun readResolve(): Any = source!!

        companion object {
            private const val serialVersionUID: Long = 1
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val serialVersionUID: Long = 42
    }
}
```

So I'm looking for a way to perform polymorphic queries over cache values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Ignite will not peer-class-load cache key/value types so you should not worry about that.
- Is it possible that you have B loaded by different class loaders? You could debug that by checking `getClass().getClassLoader()` of B's.
- Maybe Kotlin expects wrapped B type at some point?

Comment: >> Ignite will not peer-class-load cache key/value types so you should not worry about that

In this case how entry processor will be able to deserialize/update values in cache?

>>Maybe Kotlin expects wrapped B type at some point?

We don’t have inline classes, if I correctly understood your question. If not- could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: If you want your entry processors to work on key/value types (and not BinaryObject's) you should deploy these on all nodes where they are stored.

Comment: peer classloading enabled + serialization tweaks to enforce usage of optimized marshaller work fine for processors. I'm triggering one against cache a and it populates some data in cache B as well. The problem occurs when I try to traverse results from ScanQuery against cache B on application node

Comment: Please compare ClassLoader's at this point of program and tell us what happens.
Change its generic type to Object and there output `val.getClassLoader().toString()` and `B.class.getClassLoader().toString` to see what happens here.

Comment: In a similar message: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Need-help-with-Composite-Key-as-primary-Key-tc27805.html people boil down classloading issues to spring-devtools, any chance it is applicable?

Comment: thank you for hints. I have 'basic' case working now but struggle with polymorphic values in cache. Like having generic interface for B and running scan queries against it. I'll update question's description....     devtools are not used and classloaders match

Comment: I suggest backing out your changes, filing a separate ticket.